# Creating An Ember View

Tags: ember.js

So I'm tossing around an idea for a presentation for work to try to show the power of Ember.  I planned on starting at some of the primitives and showing that things can technically stand on there own, but Ember works best when you adhere to patterns. Anyways I would like to just render a view.  In the Ember Guides under view there is this example:

View

```
var view = Ember.View.create({
  templateName: 'say-hello',
  name: "Bob"
});


view.appendTo('#container');
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-1.0.0-rc.7.prod.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container"></div>



    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="say-hello">
      Hello, <b>{{view.name}}</b>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/EPuwApE/3/edit

This does not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. When you create a template, name it with the `data-template-name` attribute.
2. In order for your view to find the template, you must create an `Ember.Application` even if you don't use it.

Alternatively, if you'd prefer not to do the above, you can inline your template in the view, compile it, and set it to the view's `template` property. I commented it out as an example.

Check out this updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofULodA/1/edit).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if you needed to spin up a new Application instance

Answer (score 2):

You missed to create an instance of Ember application like

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
});
```

[Working Bin](http://jsbin.com/uZAninu/1/edit)